# Populate iphone tableview from an SQLite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, uitableview

I am trying to populate an iphone table view with values from an SQLite database.
Lets say the table is as follows:

---

**Name**        **description**         **picture**

poodle      likes to growl       poodle.jpg

cat               likes to meow       cat.jpg

...                        ...                             ...

---

How would I populate an iphone tableview to include eveything under the name column,
and then  when I click on one of the items it loads another view containing the picture and description.
PS: I'm pretty new to IOS programming.


Thank you,
Fernando Diaz

Comment: Have you read the table view programming guide? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: Thanks jtbandes, that was a good reference but, I checked it out and  I can't find anything on SQLite.

Comment: why not use CoreData? It allows you to have SQLite as the backend storage, and abstracts away all the sql related manipulations. Is it a requirement to use SQLite directly?

Comment: Agree with @Nick, Core Data is the way to go. It will take care of storing and loadin your objects directly to/from a SQLite persistent store and will even handle things like paging your results which can be a real nightmare to yourself if you're new.

Answer (score 2):

UITableView is not fill up every row at once. every time you scroll up or down it fills rows one by one, that's why you should query your SQL database first that you should keep (retain) your data in an array.

```
-(void)querySQL
{
    //query your database and prepare an array here.
    [yourTableView reloadData];
{

//here tell your table how many rows you need.
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourArray count];
}

//Fill your UITableView here
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //create cell and fill cell objects.
}
```

thanks.